# Why is this click binding not being bound?

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BxvVp/11/

I create a view model that has a function that replaces a `div` content with some hidden content on the page. Once that's done, the `text` binding appears to be processed, but the `click` binding is not.

Am I doing something wrong?

html:

```
<h4>Clicking the anchor created by clicking 'Summarize' should cause an alert, but doesn't.</h4>

<a href="#" data-bind="click: summarize">Summarize</a>

<div id="plot1"></div>
<div id="summary1" style="display:none;"> <a data-bind="text: 'anchor-text-replaced', click: function(data, event) { alert('anchor clicked!'); }" href="#">anchor-text</a>

</div>
<hr />

<h4>Clicking this anchor causes the alert as exptected.</h4>
<div id="plot2"></div>
<div id="summary2">
    <a data-bind="text: 'anchor-text-replaced', click: function(data, event) { alert('anchor clicked!'); }" href="#">anchor-text</a>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.summarize = function () {
        $("#plot1").html($("#summary1").html());
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: You have a typo in your H4, you haven't closed it

Comment: @Dave - Fixed in the fiddle and the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knockout only applies bindings when you initially call `ko.applyBindings()` and any time *Knockout* replaces HTML that contains bindings, foreach blocks, templates, etc. Just because you inserted some random HTML that contains bindings, doesn't mean Knockout is suddenly aware of that fact.

Comment: Ok. I understand. The text is bound on applyBindings, so the HTML with the replaced text already exists before it is displayed. I'll fix this by hiding/displaying the appropriate div instead of replacing HTML. Thanks!